# Does Apple use containers on a Mac?

Tags: macos

When I snoop around the file system including within my home directory I see things that look like they are containers or have something to do with containers (as in Docker containers).  For example `~/Library/Reminders/Container_v1/...`  I'm curious about these things.  I'm wondering if Apple has a container system with a MacOS inside the container rather than Linux.  Docker Desktop uses a slim VM just to run its containers because Docker containers want to have Linux based OS inside of them.  I'm wondering if Apple has developed containers which can run directly on the native system rather than inside Linux VM.  And if so, are there plans to make this available to the general public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This container isn’t a ‘unit of software’ (like a Docker container, don’t get your hopes up!) but rather a container of data used for cloud synchronisation.

Other containers for sandboxing data exist at
`~/Library/Containers` and `~/Library/Group Containers`:

Apple documentation of data containers and sandboxing exists at

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckcontainer.
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html

Comment: Aren't they also for Sandboxing? A Sandbox app can only access files and folders in its Container.

Comment: @benwiggy That's true, `~/Library/Containers`! I've added that to this answer